# Implementing Graph for Bayes Net in FSharp

Tags: python, f#

I'm trying to translate a graph formulation from Python to F#

The python "Node" class:

```
class Node:
    """ A Node is the basic element of a graph.  In its most basic form a graph is just a list of nodes.  A Node is a really just a list of neighbors.
    """
    def __init__(self, id, index=-1, name="anonymous"):
        # This defines a list of edges to other nodes in the graph.
        self.neighbors = set()
        self.visited = False
        self.id = id
        # The index of this node within the list of nodes in the overall graph.
        self.index = index
        # Optional name, most usefull for debugging purposes.
        self.name = name

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # Defines a < operator for this class, which allows for easily sorting a list of nodes.
        return self.index < other.index

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)

    def __eq__(self, right):
        return self.id == right.id

    def add_neighbor(self, node):
        """ Make node a neighbor if it is not alreadly.  This is a hack, we should be allowing self to be a neighbor of self in some graphs.  This should be enforced at the level of a graph, because that is where the type of the graph would disallow it.
        """
        if (not node in self.neighbors) and (not self == node):
            self.neighbors.add(node)

    def remove_neighbor(self, node):
        # Remove the node from the list of neighbors, effectively deleting that edge from
        # the graph.
        self.neighbors.remove(node)

    def is_neighbor(self, node):
        # Check if node is a member of neighbors.
        return node in self.neighbors
```

My F# class so far:

```
type Node<'T>= string*'T
type Edge<'T,'G> = Node<'T>*Node<'T>*'G
type Graph = 
    | Undirected of seq(Node*list Edge) 
    | Directed of seq(Node*list Edge *list Edge)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this does have to do with immutability.  F#'s Set is an immutable collection, it is based on a binary tree which supports Add, Remove and lookup in O(log n) time.

However, because the collection is immutable, the add operation returns a new Set.

```
let originalSet = set [1; 2; 7]
let newSet = originalSet.Add(5)
```

The most purely functional solution is probably to reconstruct your problem to remove the mutability entirely.  This approach would probably see you reconstruct your node class as an immutable data container (with no methods) and define the functions that act on that data container in a separate module.

```
module Nodes =
    /// creates a new node from an old node with a supplied neighbour node added.
    let addNeighbour neighbourNode node  =
        Node <| Set.add neighbourNode (node.Neighbours) 
        //Note: you'll need to replace the backwards pipe with brackets for pre-F# 4.0
```

See the immutable collections in the FSharp Core library such as List, Map, etc. for more examples.

If you prefer the mutable approach, you could just make your `neighbours` mutable so that it can be updated when the map changes or just use a mutable collection such as a `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<'T>`.

---

When it comes to the hashcode, `Set<'T>` actually doesn't make use of that.  It requires that objects that can be contained within it implement the `IComparable` interface.  This is used to generate the ordering required for the binary tree.  It looks like your object already has a concept of ordering built-in which would be appropriate to provide this behaviour.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got the hang of it...but I can't quite bring it home.  I think I'm really close though...can you check out the updated version of the F# code?

Comment: @bordeo What you've got there are just some type abbreviations.  Maybe defining your types as records (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) would be better?  They play nicely with type inference and should be easy to define custom ordering on if you need it.

Comment: Ok, so what I need is a node box that holds a name, a generic quantity, and a list of incoming Edges and outgoing Edges...

And an Edge that holds two ordered nodes, a generic quantity, and a weight...

And a graph that holds various permutations of sequence, array, lists and matrices of nodes and edges...

Comment: You need to use `and` to define mutually recursive types. `type Node<'a>={Name : string; Quantity: 'a; Incoming : Edge<'a> list; Outgoing: Edge<'a> list} and Edge<'a,'b> = {node1: Node<'a>; node2 : Node<'a>; Quantity : 'b; Weight : ...} and Graph =  ....`  Sorry I can't format the code better in here but that should hopefully get you going!